# PHP catch eval output

Tags: php, caching, buffer, eval

I wanna **catch** the output of the **eval execution** and see only the output of **$B**
, any solution for that?

If i execute the code like this i get output twice:

first from eval

second from $B

pls i dont need questions why i am using eval, and that eval is evil.

I need a solution for exactly this example.

```
<?php
  $A = '<?php echo "Output"; ?>';
  eval(" ?> $A <?php ");
  $B = ob_get_contents();
  echo $B;
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't show it so you need to start buffering with [ob_start](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).  Then get and clean the buffer so that the buffer will be empty at the end of execution [ob_get_clean](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php):

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  $A = '<?php echo "Output"; ?>';
  eval(" ?> $A <?php ");
  $B = ob_get_clean();
  echo $B;
?>
```

Alternately you could use `ob_clean` or `ob_end_clean` somewhere after the `ob_get_contents`.